# CABasicAnimation of layer is choppy

Tags: ios, core-animation

I've built a custom progress bar in a UIView object using 3 layers:

1. a layer that represents the "empty" progress bar and that I use as a background.
2. a layer that I use to measure progress that appears on top of layer 1.
3. a layer that simply draws some hashmarks on top of the progress bar.

Layer 2 is animated to stretch the bounds width from 0 to 320 evenly over a period of time, usually about 2 minutes.  It works fine but is not as smooth as I would have expected.
Any thoughts on how I could improve the performance or use other/additional animation techniques to make it appear to move more evenly?

The code that creates layer 2 is:

```
- (void)drawForegroundLayer {

CGColorRef startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGColorRef endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:239.0/255.0 green:125.0/255.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

CAGradientLayer *foregroundLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
foregroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2, 0, 13);
foregroundLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.5);
foregroundLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)startColor, (id)endColor, nil];
foregroundLayer.borderWidth = 0;
foregroundLayer.edgeAntialiasingMask = kCALayerRightEdge;

[self.layer addSublayer:foregroundLayer];
}
```

And the code that animates layer 2 is:

```
- (void)start {

CALayer *bar = [[self.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:1];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size.width"];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:320.0];
animation.duration = MAXIMUM_TIME_PER_SESSION;

[bar addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

}
```

Comment: Profile using "Core Animation profiler" instruments. Maybe you will see where to optimize in other places. Watch for offscreen rendering and too much color blending. Also watch if anything is processed in your main thread. It  slows animation too.

Comment: By "not smooth" I wonder if it's just that you are animating 320 pixels over 120 seconds. That's not an even number of pixels per second. Is it better at 80 seconds?